# GDCM: getting tag value

Tags: c++, gdcm

I am trying to read and write the attribute values of a dicom file.
The interfaces shall be something like this:

```
// only need to support std::string, int, float, float*, etc.
template<class T>
T getTagValue(const DataSet& ds, const Tag& tag);

template<class T>
void setTagValue(DataSet& ds, const Tag& tag, const T& value);
```

The [FAQ of GDCM](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Using_GDCM_API) gives some great examples of how to get an attribute value, but these examples don't work like what I thought.

Here are my questions about these examples.

1. how can I convert the attribute value to its type?

   ```
   if( header.FindDataElement( Tag(0x2, 0x13 ) )
        DataElement &de = header.GetDataElement( Tag(0x2, 0x13) );
   ```
2. What if the attribute value is an array?

   ```
    sf=gdcm.StringFilter()
    sf.SetFile(r.GetFile())
    print sf.ToStringPair(gdcm.Tag(0x0028,0x0010))
   ```
3. Actually, I really like the following solution. But does this means that I have to write an interface for EVERY attribute?

   ```
    const DataSet &ds = file.GetDataSet();
    Attribute<0x0020,0x0032> at;
    at.Set( ds );
    if( at.GetValue() == 0.0 ) exit(1);
   ```

Any suggestions will be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've posted an exact copy/paste message on the GDCM mailing list:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/gdcm/mailman/message/34736982/

And I've answered your question here:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/gdcm/mailman/message/34737182/

For convenience here it is again:

> gdcm::Attribute is really only meant for people dealing with specific
>   attribute. If you do not now the Tag ahead of time and only the
>   underlying type of the Data Element, then have a look at
>   gdcm::Element<>.

Comment: Yes, I just hoped to get the best practice for this question. And I didn't expect someone saw this question on both side. Thanks for your answer again. :)